# Partitioning densed data points using clustering

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have to cluster data which are power profiles of the solar panel output. I tried various algorithm including **classical K-means to shape based clustering** as well. I have to decide number of cluster possible in the pool of data. And I am always getting 2 cluster, so I think they are very dense.

Is there any way I can partition dense cluster?

Comment: Which language are you using? Could you please add the code you have so far?

Comment: **Visualize** your data, and include your best visualization in the question, please. And yes, maybe your data does not contain clusters at all... That is why you need to visualize.

Comment: @alber I am currently using Matlab to do so. And I have various functions so pasting the code over here wont be appropriate. Thing is i am not concern about the code but the method or any different measure i can use.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It is very difficult to visually as there are approx 1000 of time series. here is glance of it [ http://imgur.com/a/9kLEI ].

Comment: well, you didn't e.g. say its time series. With such data, consider extrscting features *first* that capture the interesting properties. Blindly running k-means on such data is bound to fsil. Never assume clustering is a black box that will just magically work - because it won't.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks mate !!! any suggestion on extracting features.

Comment: Finally, I got success in finding the number of cluster, well best is two but if we allow some distortion in the cluster then we can select the next best value after two. Since data was extracted from real life, it is possible that they are inseparable and thus overlap.